# How to get the unique id for each email?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I need help to get the unique id for each email?

This is my code:

```
$config = array('host'=> 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'user' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'ssl' => 'SSL');


   $mail = new Zend\Mail\Storage\Imap($config);
   $a=0;
   foreach ($mail as $mensaje) {
      $a++;
      $id=$mail->getUniqueId($a);
      $idx=$mail->getNumberByUniqueId($id);
      echo "<a href='../Contenido/contenido?Id=$idx'> {$mensaje->from}: {$mensaje->subject}-  Key - {$mail->key()} </a>  <br>";

    }
```

But do not bring me a unique id.

Comment: Have you escaped `$mensaje->subject`? It seems not - consider what would happen if this contains an opening angle bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're getting the message ID here

```
$id=$mail->getUniqueId($a);
```

but then you're using the unique ID you retrieved to get the message number (which you already had as **$a**).

The variable **$id** should hold the unique ID, and $idx is unnecessary.